# typescript error Expected 0 type arguments for get call

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I am getting typescript error Expected 0 type arguments, but got 1 for line that returns get call. What is wrong with my get call?

```
 public get(params: SummaryParams): Observable<Summary[]> {
        const uri = `${this.config.URLS.LOAD_SUMMARY}`;
        const params = new HttpParams()
                      .set('startDate', params.startDate.toString())
                      .set('endDate', params.endDate.toString())
                      .set('userId', params.userId);

        return this.http.get<Summary[]>(uri, { params });
      }
```

Comment: http.get should get just uri, try using post method

Comment: @Arash Actually, that's not true. It takes an optional `options` object as well https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient#get

Comment: you are correct, but I still agree with post request :D . when you wanna post data to back-end , you should use post method.

Comment: @Arash It's not evident that data is posted. It could be search query.

Comment: You can change the last line to return <Summary[]>this.http.get(uri, { params });

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`HttpClient` has generic methods that can be used to provide response type. `Http` doesn't.

The error means that `<Summary[]>` generic parameter wasn't expected, and `http` isn't an instance of `HttpClient`; likely an instance of `Http`.

If the application uses Angular 4.3 or higher, `Http` should be replaced with `HttpClient`. In case `Http` should be used, a response should be transformed, this is one of few differences between `HttpClient` and `Http`:

```
    return this.http.get(uri, { params })
    .map(res => <Summary[]>res.json());
```

Comment: Because I had to look it up in the official angular docs: The variable name for an instance of ``HttpClient`` is still recommended to be ``http``.

Comment: I had this error because my editor added the http import even though I already had HttpClient. So check for "import * as http from 'http';"