# Expected 0 type arguments, but got 1 - angular 7

Tags: angular

i am creating Material Auto-complete With Asyng Data coming from an API.
but this problem shows up. i followed the "https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-autocomplete-async2?file=src%2Fapp%2Fuser.class.ts" on this link. and just simply replacing the manual population of array of data mechanism into an api mechanism.

IUserResponse in "this.http.get< IUserResponse >" is underlined red and error was "Expected 0 type arguments, but got 1"

//////app.service .ts

```
search(filter: {companyName: string} = {companyName: ''}): Observable<IUserResponse> {
    return this.http.get<IUserResponse>(this.api+'PublicAPI/Schools',this.option)
    .pipe(
      tap((response: IUserResponse) => {
        response.results = response.results
          .map(user => new Schoollist(user.companyID, user.companyName))
          .filter(user => user.companyName.includes(filter.companyName))
        return response;
      })
      );
  }
```

/////schoollist.class.ts

```
export class Schoollist {
    constructor(public companyID: string, public companyName: string) {}
}
export interface IUserResponse {
  total: string;
  results: Schoollist[];
}
```

///app.component.ts

````
filteredSchs: Schoollist[] = [];
  usersForm: FormGroup;
  isLoading = false;

  constructor(public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<EducationalbackgroundUpdateComponent>,
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any,
    public dialog: MatDialog,
    private global: GlobalService,
    private http: Http,
    private fb: FormBuilder,
    ) { 

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.usersForm = this.fb.group({
      userInput: null
    })

      this.usersForm
      .get('userInput')
      .valueChanges
      .pipe(
        debounceTime(300),
        tap(() => this.isLoading = true),
        switchMap(value => this.global.search({companyName: value})
        .pipe(
          finalize(() => this.isLoading = false),
          )
        )
      )
      .subscribe(users => this.filteredSchs = users.results);
  }

  displayFn(sch: Schoollist) {
    if (sch) { return sch.companyName; }
  }```
````

Comment: *his problem shows up*: **which** problem? Where does it happen?

Answer (score 0):

You might be using `Http` and not `HttpClient`? If you are using HttpClient then `get()` should allow type arguments, on the other hand, `Http` doesn't allow it.

*Source: [typescript error Expected 0 type arguments for get call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50665404/typescript-error-expected-0-type-arguments-for-get-call)*

Make sure you import: `import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';` and have it in your constructor: `constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}`

Comment: i just tried to use HttpClient. and this error shows up 
error TS2345: Argument of type 'OperatorFunction<IUserResponse, IUserResponse>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'OperatorFunction<HttpEvent<IUserResponse>, IUserResponse>'.
  Type 'IUserResponse' is not assignable to type 'HttpEvent<IUserResponse>'.
    Type 'IUserResponse' is not assignable to type 'HttpUserEvent<IUserResponse>'.
      Property 'type' is missing in type 'IUserResponse'.

Comment: Did you add this `observe?: 'body';` in your `this.option` ?

Comment: There might be something wrong with your options or with what you get back from your backend. Can you show what options you are using and what your api calls return?

Comment: ```
this.option = new RequestOptions({ headers: this.header });
```
{
    "companyID": "17598",
    "companyName": "A.H. Lacson Elementary School",
    "address": null
  },.......

Comment: i just removed this.option and this shows up when i compiled the project ```ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined```

Comment: Can you create a Stackblitz of your project? That would make it simpler to fix :)

Comment: i just followed this link https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-autocomplete-async2?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.service.ts...and just simply inserted my API

Comment: Also, do not remove the `this.options`. Instead in its place, put `this.option = { observe: 'body', responseType: 'json' }` and try. If you want to pass params to your api, add `params: { ...names.. }` to your this.option. You are getting your response.result as undefined.